# Adding a pdf file instead of an image in the joomla mediamanager

Tags: pdf, joomla

I would like to add a pdf file to the joomla media manager, and then select it as a full article image, so that I can get the link using json and echo it for every product, without having to manually add a pdf link every time.

However when I want to link the pdf file to an article, and browse to the folder where the pdf file is located, it says: 'No images found'.

Is it possible to add pdf files to an article instead of an image, using the media manager?

This is where I browse to my pdf file:

https://i.gyazo.com/8ef91fc2d1ea26a36abcfb22bcc0cd25.png

Answer (score 0):

**Hello @twan**,

I can see only solution to your question is : [PDF Embed Plugin from Techjoomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/pdf-embed)

Try using this extension and let me know if it works for you or not.

Thanks,
Mrunal.

Comment: Is it not possible to remove a filter for the media manager? So it also recognizes pdf files instead of only images? This actually embeds the whole pdf file inside an article, that is not what I want. I want to create a link to a pdf file, and connect that link to the article somehow. But I cannot do that using the media manager because it only allows images to be selected.

Comment: You can try this Joomla! editor which will easily allow you to add links of pdf file in joomla content, but be sure you select this editot as default editor from Joomla! Global Configuration.
 https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/editor

Comment: Yeah I know this can be done, but that is not what I am looking for. I want to be able to browse to a pdf file, and link it to an article (not directly make it visible) and then in php, get the link from the database and echo that link in my own style inside a foreach loop.

Comment: Oh yes, then there is no straight way to do this. You will require customization with core joomla! extension and libraries for this.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm trying to find out where to edit that, but I have no idea :P